# Composition of function with itself

Tags: functions

For the set of all functions $f:\{0,1, \dots,2014\} \to \{0,1,\dots, 2014\}$ such that $f\left(f\left(i\right)\right)=i$, for all $0 \leq i \leq 2014$.

Consider the following statements:

$A$ : For each such function it must be the case that for every $i,f(i) = i$

$B$ : For each such function it must be the case that for some  $i,f(i) = i$

$C$ : Each function must be onto.

Which statements are correct, and why?

---

I tried this question using the same problem for a small set where $f:\{0,1\}\rightarrow\,\{0,1\}$.

It is found that statement $C$ always holds true and statement $A$ does not. I choose $B$ to be not true but in solution key it is marked true. Cannot understand the reason for that.

Comment: What have you tried?  Hint:  start by analyzing the same question replacing $2014$ by a small number, like $1$ or $2$.

Comment: I don't know how to deal with these questions. 
I tried and found that if $f$ is taken as an identity function then option $C$ has to be true. That's only I have concluded to, cannot proceed. Please suggest something.

Comment: Well, it's much easier to think about the same problem for a small set; so look at $f:\{0,1\}\rightarrow\,\{0,1\}$.  Now there are only $4$ possible functions, so you can simply enumerate them.  Can you find a non-trivial example that satisfies the desired equality?

Comment: $A$ can never be marked as true for all cases, but it may work in some when the function is identity.
Whenever $f\left(f\left(i\right)\right)=i$ condition holds then $C$ is true.

But what can we say about $B$?

Comment: Not following.  Certainly the identity function always satisfies your equality.  The question is, can you write down a non-trivial function that does.  $B$ is somewhat subtle.  Did you find a non-trivial example from $\{0,1\}$ to itself?  Does it satisfy $B$?  does the same sort of function generalize to, say, functions from $\{0,1,2\}$ to itself?

Comment: function $f:\{0,1\}\rightarrow\,\{0,1\}$ where
$f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$ fails to satisfy $f(i) = i$ for any $i$. So, statement $B$ fails here. When $B$ fails in this case then why there is still a need to check for a $f:\{0,1, 2\}\rightarrow\,\{0,1, 2\}$?

Comment: Because there is a parity issue...see my posted solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ is false in general, consider the example: $$f(i) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $i=0$} \\
0, & \text{if $i=1$}\\
i,& \text{if $i>1$}
\end{cases}$$

$C$ is true, clearly.

$B$ is also true, but this is more subtle. In particular it is true only because $2014$ is an even number. To see this, consider the pairing $(i,f(i))$ If there were no fixed points then each of those pairs consists of two elements.  Clearly the pairs are disjoint and every element of $\{0,1,\dots, 2014\}$ is in exactly one of them.  But that is absurd...there are $2015$ elements of the set and $2015$ is odd.